# Eliminate time checking when entering captcha when creating multi-account software on kolotibablo

Tags: java, javafx, webview

I want to create a captcha typing software for multiple accounts with the website https://kolotibablo.com/

I have problem when captcha appear [image]

if for a few seconds I don't enter a character in the input box.It will disappear.I am using javafx's webview.I use the code to enter a few random characters.

```
webView.getWebEngine().executeScript("document.getElementById(\"guesstext\").value = \"RANDOM\"");
```

I want to keep the process checked before I go back to typing it.Please help me

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't know any reason why somebody would help you write a program that guesses captchas here.